# Reading one CSS for multiple JSPs

Tags: css, jsp

I have a good amount of jsp files (about 40) in a single folder and hey all share common classes and ids, however each of them were written with inline styling.

My question is; what would be the most effective/time-efficient way to override each of their inline styling properties without going through and modifying each jsp individually - Is there any way to override from a CSS file without using the `!important` tag?

Cheers!

Comment: I believe in Dreamweaver you can turn all inline styling into a separate file. So if you have access to both of those you can just export all inline styles to a separate doc

Comment: Inline styles have the highest priority of all CSS. You should avoid them. You should agregate your styles into css file, and use classes and ids for your components.

Comment: Thanks Adjit I'll check it out. And I didn't write the program unfortunately, but I do agree @loan

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small jquery function to remove the inline styles. This is not an ideal solution and I think manually removing the styling would be the best way forward. BUT if you needed a quicker solution, this function below will remove all inline styling on the page.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/rpLS3/1/

Example:

```
$('body *').removeAttr('style');
```